# React pass multi state between two components

Tags: reactjs, state

i found a [gist](https://gist.github.com/sebkouba/a5ac75153ef8d8827b98) about how to pass state between two components.

Here the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tipixiy/edit?js,output)

But how about the multi state?

I want two input fields and show the entered text in other components when i edit it.

i tried edited like this

```
this.state = {
  fieldVal: "" //first input state
  otherFieldVal: "" //second
}
```

and

```
  //input onChange
  onUpdate = name => (event) => {
    this.setState({ [name]: event.target.value });
  };
```

with no luck.

How can i made it work on multi state for multi input fields ?

Comment: are you looking for a solution like this https://jsbin.com/locoqisaqo/edit?js,output ?

Comment: cool, but if i have many many input and state and i dont wanna repeat myself for pass the passedVal1={this.state.fieldVal1}, passedVal2={this.state.fieldVal2}, and 3 and 4, can i use this.setState({ [name]: event.target.value }) in this case? I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: can you check my answer once ? and check this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fsrkp2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't need to keep state in both Child and parent. You can write your child component like below, and you can access tow states dynamically by using **data-attirb** or you can folloe @Isaac 's answer.Keep the state in Child and pass state to Parent or keep the event to Parent from Child.

```
 export class Child extends React.Component {

  update = (e) => {
    this.props.onUpdate(e.target)
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Child</h4>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="type here"
          onChange={this.update}
         data-state = "fieldVal"
          value={this.props.fieldVal}
        /><br/><br/>
      <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="type here"
          onChange={this.update}
      data-state = "otherFieldVal"
          value={this.props.otherFieldVal}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export class OtherChild extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>OtherChild</h4>
        Value in OtherChild Props passedVal1: {this.props.passedVal1} <br/>
      Value in OtherChild Props passedVal2: {this.props.passedVal2}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and in parent :

```
class App extends Component {

  onUpdate = (data) => {
    this.setState({
      [data.dataset.state]: data.value
    })
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Parent</h2>
        Value in Parent Component State fieldVal: {this.state.fieldVal} <br/>
        Value in Parent Component State otherFieldVal: {this.state.otherFieldVal}
        <br/>
        <Child onUpdate={this.onUpdate} fieldVal= {this.state.fieldVal} otherFieldVal ={this.state.otherFieldVal}/>
        <br />
        <OtherChild passedVal1={this.state.fieldVal} passedVal2={this.state.otherFieldVal}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fsrkp2)

Comment: nice, i changed to pass state with 'state={this.state}' and show the state with '{this.props.state.fieldVal}' so i dont have to repeat myself now if i have 100 input and state :) is there another good way to do same result?

Comment: Yes there's an other option , will suggest that too now :)

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ydyazj,  you can store N no of inputs values in an array this example demonstrating that.

Answer (score 0):

```js
renderInput = (prop) => {
  return (
    <Input 
      onChange={(event) => {
        this.setState({ [prop]: event.target.value });
      }}
    />
  )
}

render() {
  <div>
    {this.renderInput('name')}
    {this.renderInput('age')}
  </div>
}
```

We can set a `renderInput` method and render different input using parameter to achieve your objective